# How to set text of a button contained within a dynamically inflated view?

Tags: android

I'm trying to dynamically set the text of a button that I'm inflating at runtime, but the text isn't being set.

I'm creating a custom Dialog for which I set `SetContentView` with a `View` that I inflate at runtime. The view contains a single `Button`, e.g:

```
var dialog = new SetUnsetDialog();

var view = View.Inflate(_context, Resource.Layout.view_set_unset_buttons, null);

view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnPartsetA).Text = _blockDescriptions["partseta"];

dialog.SetContentView(view);
dialog.SetTitle("Set/Unset " + _area);
dialog.Show();
```

The layout is defined as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- irrelevant stuff removed -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutSetUnsetButtons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center">

        <!-- irrelevant stuff removed -->

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnPartsetA"
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/partset_a" />            

        <!-- irrelevant stuff removed -->

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Why is the button text not being set? What do I need to do to set it?

**UPDATE:**

It turns out this is a non-issue. The content view gets reset later and overwrites the values that I set.

Comment: Are you using some sort of library for syntax?  Because that is not standard Java/Android.

Comment: It's C#/Xamarin (aka Mono for Android). Everything's the same as with Java except the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

what about using the `setText` method instead of `.Text`?